# Many socket connections to a server

Tags: multithreading, sockets

I am writing a client-server application for the exchange of short messages (no chat). My approach is to give each client an own thread on the server, which handles the communication. I have not done this before, and I am not sure how many of these threads can run in parallel. Can you give me a help here?

Now a client 1 can send something to the server, and at some point, the server has to send this information to another client 2. The socket connection between client 2 and the server must be a permanent connection to ensure that the server can send information at any time, right?

Comment: Does nobody have an idea?

Comment: 'not sure how many of these threads can run in parallel' - typically, some small number of thousands. 'The socket connection between client 2 and the server must be a permanent connection to ensure that the server can send information at any time' - yes.

Comment: Test it.  Start your server and make lots of clients.  See how the system behaves.